# How do I add a selection between two tags in a html document using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Let's say that I have the following html paragraph:
`<p>This is a nice paragraph</p>`

Is there a quick way to emphasise, for example, the word 'nice'?
If I write <em> before 'nice', my paragraph will look like this:
`<p>This is a <em></em>nice paragraph</p>`
Because of this, I have to copy 'nice' and paste it between the two <em> tags and I feel that it would be time consuming over a long period.
Is there a way to select the word 'nice' and then write <em> to instantly get it between the tags, and not to get it replaced by the tags?

Comment: look at `Emmet: Wrap Selection`, you can add this to a keybinding, and have a key to wrap with the `em` tag

Comment: Thank you for your answer rioV8. This  was really useful. Sorry for the long wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is Embedded Emmet.

1. In Visual Studio Code, press Ctrl + Shift + P (which opens Command Palette).
2. Execute: `Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation`
3. Enter a tag e.g. `div` (or an abbreviation `.wrapper>p`)
4. Press Enter

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: It would be nice to give a mention +1 in your answer to the commenter that said this a few days ago.

Comment: Thank you for detailing what rioV8 said! This really helps.